# Confusion from Griffith's Electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, polarization, dielectric

In Griffith's Electrodynamics chapter 4: Electric Field in Matter - when he derives the Gauss's Law for dielectric he just ignores the surface-bound charge and gives the reason for doing it as

> It may have appeared to you that I left out the surface bound charge  ***σ*** in deriving equation 4.22(Differential form of gauss's law for dielectrics) and in a sense that is true. We cannot apply gauss's law precisely at the surface of a dielectric, for here the volume bound charge density blows up, taking the divergence with it. Everywhere else the logic is sound, and in fact if we picture the edge of the dielectric as having some finite thickness within which the polarization tapers off to zero (**probably more realistic model than an abrupt cut-off anyway**), ***then there is no surface bound charge;*** volume charge density varies rapidly but smoothly within this "skin" and Gauss's Law can be safely applied everywhere.

Now My Question is if the surface bound charge is assumed or at least for the sake of this model is zero then **there exists only volume bound charge! But it is evident that *(in my knowledge that's is a mathematical consequence I do not have any idea about experimental justification)* surface bound charge exists**!
So I am trying to understand if he means that in reality surface bound charges are actually contained in a very small volume v(tends to zero) as we can model them as volume charge and there is no existence of surface charge at all! But to do this we have to be careful because as the **polarization will vary very very rapidly in the skin** that's why we cannot simply use the polarization variation that we have used so far in the rest of the volume(except the skin with finite thickness no matter how much small) because then we have to deduce a new function that's why in solving problems we readily use surface bound charge rather than volume bound charge!

Any kind of Help is appreciated!

Comment: So what is the question? You have a lot of exclamation marks and no question marks. Surface charges are used in some cases, where it is convenient. Usually one expresses them via the boundary conditions. Use of surface charges can simplify a problem but also leads to appearance of generalized functions (delta functions, step functions etc) in the equations, and one then has to treat them carefully. Is this what you are after?

Comment: One can always solve the problem with finite thickness of charge-carrying layer, and then let the thickness go to zero, whilst keeping the total charge in the layer finite. That's another way to arrive at surface charges. In reality surface charges will always penetrate into the bulk, but penetration depth maybe to a very small.

Comment: My question is can I consider surface charge as a volume charge for a finite thickness of the skin on the surface?[and to do that we cannot use the same polarization function that we have used in the rest of the volume(except the very small finite skin) of the dielectrics]

Comment: So in this case, sure you can. Exactly how small the thickness of your finite thickness layer has to be becomes a bit tricky, but it should be possible to determine for the specific situation at hand. For surface charge, in units of Charge/Area, you will have surface polarization in units of 'electric dipole'/Area. For volume charge, in units of Charge/Volume, you will have polarization in units of 'electric dipole'/Volume. The normal route from per volume to per are quantity is to assume finite thickness and average over this thickness (integrate with respect to thickness)